# Displaying All Global Parameters In XSLT

Tags: xslt

I would like to know if there is a way to view all the Global Parameters in XSLT without explicitly knowing the name.

ie

```
<xsl:param name="T"/>
```

In my cms I have a text box whereby I may enter "T=whatever,A=dave" These parameters are then added programmaticly for access within the XSLT document. Now supposing i do not have source access, is there any way to expose the parameters name and value without knowing the name to begin with?

Kind Regards,
Samuel Lilleker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *must* already have an `xsl:param` defined with the same name in your XSLT transformation -- otherwise a value cannot be passed to non-existent parameter.

And there is no-way to find the (dynamic) values of global parameters if you don't know the parameter names statically.

It is possible to have something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="vGlobalParamValues" select=
 "document('')/*/xsl:param/@select
|
  document('')/*/xsl:param[not(@select)]/node()
 "/>
```

But this selects only the compile-time values of the parameters and could return something like:

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

which, of course is not the result of actually applying the templates.

A correct way to pass unknown name-value pairs as parameters is to make them part of a *single* global parameter, such as:

```
<xsl:param name="pParams">
 <param name="someName1">someValue1</param>
 <param name="someName2">someValue2</param>

  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .

 <param name="someNameN">someValueN</param>
</xsl:param>
```

Comment: thanks, is this the same in both xslt v1 and v2? For some reason it seems like an odd oversight to me! I think in the future I will ask my man to pass parameters in the format you suggest.

Comment: @Treemonkey: This is the same. However, in XSLT 2.0 one can use a facility called "tunnel parameters" (of which I am not a fan of). A tunnel parameter needs to be defined only at the starting and ending point (the actual sender and the actual receiver) of a chain of templates each of which invokes the next in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Some XSLT processor APIs may allow you to discover the names of the stylesheet parameters. But if the API doesn't provide this, it's easy enough to get it from the source code: this is one of the things you get for free because XSLT syntax is XML.

Comment: Does Saxonica allow you to discover the names of the stylesheet parameters?  I'd like to get all the parameters passed to transform:transform from XQL, not knowing in advance what the parameters are which have been passed.

Comment: Please don't ask supplementary questions in the form of comments on a 10-year old answer to a different question. Start a new thread.